# Is pickling/unpickling query safe?

Tags: django, celery, sql-injection

I have a Celery task that accepts a query built from a Table data as an argument:

```
    query = self.data.data.query
    response = ExportTableTask.delay_or_fail(query=query)
```

Within the Celery task I'm re-adding the query to a query set to replicate the results:

```
def task(query):
    data = Model.objects.all()
    data.query = query
```

My concern is whether or not this transfer of the pickled query is safe, and if it is being further sanitised when being re-added to a queryset.

Or if somebody gained access to the task broker, would they be able to inject any SQL they like?

Answer (score 0):

You can pickle, how to do it correctly is described on [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets).

If someone get access to the message he can have fun, the pickle is just a binary representation of the object it's enough to generate a valid query object in the format you are expecting and he can do lot of damages.

However broker should be secured with TSL and users created with strong passwords for avoid injection of messages.
Another approach is to have the broker in an isolated network together with celery workers, is secure and fast.